# A question arises or is raised?

Tags: word-usage

Which one is correct for a formal paper?

> A question which arises, is whether people should watch Tv or not?

or

> A question which is raised, is whether people should watch Tv or not?

Thank you.

Comment: << A question which arises is whether people should watch TV or not. >> focuses on the fact of the question arising. Indeed, it could mean << When you think about it, the whole question of whether or not people should watch TV needs to be considered. >>  But  << A question which is raised is whether people should watch TV or not. >> brings focus on the people involved in raising the question, as well as on the question itself.

Comment: Both are possible, depending on the intended meaning. But first, get rid of the comma -- punctuation between subject and verb is not (generally) permitted. In the second, the subject contains is a passive relative clause where a _by_ phrase could be inserted, cf. "A question which is raised by many people is whether people should watch TV or not"? Note also that the relative clause could be replaced by the gerund-participial "arising".

Answer (score 3):

"Arises" means that it comes up: possibly because someone asked it, but this isn't specified.  In this instance, you could be saying that it's a question which people often think of themselves.

"Raised" means that **somebody raised it**.  This makes the reader think "Who by?".  Depending on the context, either could be correct, but the latter expects you to have already mentioned the people who might have raised the question.

In many cases, these might mean the same thing - it might be impossible for it to arise without someone actually raising it.

EDIT - explained the difference better, thanks to Mr Lister in the comments :)

Comment: That's true.  i don't think I worded that very well.  Can you explain the difference better?  It's to do with less of a reference to a "raiser".

Comment: That's the difference between a question coming up and a question being brought up, yes, that there is no mention of a "raiser" in the former. But that doesn't mean there _is_ no raiser.

Comment: PS I'm not a native English speaker, so you should be able to word it better than me!